# Dynamic char** array in c

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I am trying to execute a execv() command, the second parameter is a list of arguments to pass.

My arguments are currently held in a string format i.e

`--config=moo --console --something=moo2 --path="this can have spaces" --format=x`

What I'd like to do is split this up into `char**` parmeters i.e

```
argv[0] = "--config=moo"
argv[1] = "--console"
```

What I don't quite get is one thing (and apologies, its been a very long time since I last used C). If I want to build a string up to put into this argv array how would I do it, for example :-

```
char* argv[10];
char* myPath = getMyPath();
argv[0] = "--config=moo";
argv[1] = ... ... ... 
...
...
argv[10] = "--path=" + myPath;
```

I believe this wouldn't be allowed in C since I have to allocate all memory in advance so by allocating the argv to be 10 elements, I can't then go and define each one individually.. or can I?

I know the + modifier doesn't work in C, but I'm unsure what function I would need to replicate it (I realise I can use strcat to add to an existing defined array, but didn't think this would work with a newly formed array)

Comment: Welcome to the world of C string manipulation... It's easy, but first, only try to realize the truth... There are no strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General malloc

[man malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) may be helpful. `malloc` takes the `minimum` number of bytes you need of memory (i.e. `malloc` can choose to provide you more). So if you need exactly `10` elements in your `char` array, it may be best to simply allocate `char* argv[10]` as you have already done. However, this creates a container for exactly 10 `char*` which are not yet defined. Thus, for each `char*`, `argv[0]...argv[9]` you can define exactly what goes in there. For instance, if you want to malloc a string of size 200 for `argv[0]`, you would use a statement as follows (notice that `200` can be held in either a constant or a variable):

```
argv[0] = malloc(200 * sizeof(char));
```

Generally, `sizeof(char) == 1 byte`, so this value is probably going to try to get 200 bytes. However, at this point you can modify `argv[0]` in any way you need to (i.e. `strncpy`, `strncat`, etc.).

Now, if you do not know how many arguments you may have, you can allocate your container on the fly. So instead of `char* argv[10]`, you can try to allocate a `char** argv`. To do this, you would execute the following statement:

```
int SOME_SIZE = 1500 ; // Or some dynamic value read, etc.
char** argv = malloc(SOME_SIZE * sizeof(char*));
```

Often times the `sizeof(char*) == 4 bytes` on a 32-bit system (size of a typical pointer). Now you can use this chunk of memory, `argv`, in a similar way that has been done before. For ease of thinking about this, using `malloc` in this way allowed you to perform a relatively equivalent operation of `char* argv[WITH_SOME_DYNAMIC_NUMBER]`. Thus, you can manipulate this new container in a similar way as I have described above.

Remember though, when you are done with memory created by `malloc`, you must call `free` or else it will not be deallocated until the program terminates.

### Your Problem

If I understand your question correctly, you have a flattened string which you want to turn into a string array for `execve`. I will work out a simple example trying to explain one of the many ways this can be done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void someMethod()
{
  char* argv[10];
  char* path = getMyPath();

  // Notice - this is a little messy and can/should be encapsulated away in another
  // method for ease of use - this is to explicitly show, however, how this can work.
  argv[9] = malloc((strlen(path) + strlen("--path=") + 1) * sizeof(char));
  strncpy(argv[9], "--path=", strlen("--path="));
  argv[9][strlen("--path=")] = '\0'; // NULL-terminate since strncpy doesn't
  strncat(argv[9], path, strlen(path));

  // Do stuff with array
  printf("%s\n", argv[9]);

  // Technically, you should never get here if execve succeeds since it will blow this
  // entire program away (unless you are fork()'ing first)
  free(argv[9]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can malloc the memory that strcat() will use, or you can use a larger-than-needed `char buffer[N]` on the stack.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


const char * someFunction();

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

  const char[] path = "commandName";
  const char[] arg1 = "--config=moo";
  const char[] arg2 = "--console";
  const char[] arg3 = "--something=moo2";
  //arg4 is skiiped
  const char[] arg5 = "--format=x";

  const char * mypath = someFunction();
  const char[] pathprefix = "--path=";

  size_t pathprefixlength = strlen(pathprefix);
  size_t stringlength =  pathprefixlength + strlen(mypath);

  char * arg4 = (char *)malloc(stringlength + 1);

  strcpy(arg4, pathprefix);
  strcpy(arg4 +  pathprefixlength, mypath);

  arg4[stringlength] = '\0'; //null terminate
  char *argvec[7]; // array of pointers
  argvec[0] = path;
  argvec[1] = arg1;
  argvec[2] = arg2;
  argvec[3] = arg3;
  argvec[4] = arg4;
  argvec[5] = arg;
  argvec[6] = NULL;
  //do something with argvec;
  free(arg4);
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a sample on how to malloc the memory that it'll use? I think my biggest issue is that its a array of an array of chars here, probably just confusing myself.

Comment: It contributed yes thanks, I've voted up, afraid RageD slightly beat you to an answer though.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* strcata(char* s1, char* s2){
    char *p;
    p=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1));
    if(p == NULL) return NULL;

    *p='\0';

    return strcat(strcat(p, s1), s2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *p;

    p=strcata("--path=", ".:./bin");
    printf("%s\n", p);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use malloc for dynamic memory allocation

For Example let say we have following simple structure:

```
struct myRecord {

 char firstName[60];

 char lastName[60];

 int employeeID;

 struct myRecord * nextRecord;

};

struct myRecord * headPtr; // point to first structure in the list
// This line allocates memory for the first record:
headPtr = (struct myRecord *)malloc(sizeof(myRecord));
```